# Symfony2 - Entity and Relationship Annotation

Tags: sql, entity-framework, symfony, relationship

This is classic method for the entity relationship;

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
 */
protected $products;
```

and other entity;

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $category;
```

But, when I use this method, I can't use limit function. All results are taken. But, I should use sql limit function. So, I use a repository class. I wrote all sql code again. I used join function again. Is the relationsip annotation necessary in this situation? Do I still need to add this annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way of doing what are you asking. You are gonna have to write a custom DQL, preferably inside a custom repository in order to fetch exactly what you want. Of course you still need the annotation itself, as is required by Doctrine to do many things under the hood and, in general, to keep a good relationship model between your entities.

The most close annotation you have to control the way in which relationships are joined when using automatic method is the `OrderBy` one:

```
/*
 * @OneToMany(...)
 * @OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
 */
 protected $relation;
```